# Ref is undefined on useLayoutEffect when using props.children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a minimal reproducable example with a component `<Wrapper>` that wraps `<Base>`. The goal is to have an input field that is focused right after rendering. ([codepen](https://codepen.io/NeroVanbiervliet/pen/oNLJazB))

Because of the wrapper, the `inputRef.current` is undefined in the `useLayoutEffect` function. The app crashes.

However, when leaving out the `<Wrapper>` component, everything works fine. ([codepen 2](https://codepen.io/NeroVanbiervliet/pen/rNLoqzV))

The buggy code:

```js
function Wrapper({ children }) {
  <div className="wrapper">
    {children}
  </div>
}

function Base() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);  
  
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Edit: the problem is not reproducable in a codepen for now. It might be because the Wrapper contains a component from [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wrapper` isn't returning anything, so you end up with nothing on the page. The fix is to add a return statement to `Wrapper`.

```
function Wrapper({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

P.S, if you check the developer console, you'll see an error alerting you to the fact that nothing was returned when rendering.

Comment: Ough, you're right! I updated the pen and it seems to work now. But in my local dev environment the problem persists. I'll check what differences there are. It's a lot larger wrapper, but the problem might be something else...

Comment: Ok, I replaced the wrapper in my app by the simple one above and the problem is not present in that case. So I confirmed that the wrapper is doing some strange things. It might be because it contains a component from [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal). In any case, thanks for the help!